# Find the expected claim payment made for a car loss

Tags: probability

> An auto insurance policy has a deductible of 1 and a maximum claim
>   payment of 5. Auto loss amounts follow an exponential distribution
>   with mean 2. Calculate the expected claim payment made for an auto
>   loss.

### Attempt

Let $L$ be the loss amount. Let $Y$ be the payment made by insurance. We know

$$ Y = \begin{cases} 0, \; \; \; 0 \leq L \leq 1 \\ \max(5, L-1), \; \; \; 1 \leq L  \end{cases} $$

We are given that $L$ had density $f_L(x) = \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}x} $. Thus, we want

$$ E(Y) = \int_1^{\infty} \max(5,x-1) \frac{1}{2} e^{-1/2x}dx $$

IS this the correct approach?

Comment: Yea what you wrote is pretty good. Except that the integral starts from 0 I think. Then you can break the integral in two at x=6.

Comment: @MaxFt Lower bound of 1 is fine.  If damages are less than 1, nothing is paid.

Comment: As the maximum payment is 5, but you have a deductible of 1, why you do not use 6 instead of 5 in the integral limit? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your statement is mostly correct. The only thing wrong in your statement is the expectation of $Y$ is the minimum of 5 and $x-1$ as once the claim is greater than 6 you will only be paying 5.

$$E(Y)=\int_{1}^{6} (x-1)f(x) dx +\int_{6}^{\infty} 5f(x) dx$$

Hope this helps

Comment: As the maximum payment is 5, but you have a deductible of 1, why you do not use 6 instead of 5 in the integral limit? Thanks!